# Images under WebContent folder displayed as document Spring

Tags: java, eclipse

[Directory Structure :Check the image under WebContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmh0b.png)

> As depicted in the image the file ".jpg" is displayed as document. Is there any way how i could resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change **System Default Editor** to **External Editors**

Have a look at [THIS](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-6a.htm)

> The external program will be used as the default editor if that program is registered as the system default editor for that file type and no other editor is registered for that file type in the Workbench. For example, on most systems the default editor for JPEG files is an application for editing or viewing image files. If there is no other editor associated with .jpg or .jpeg files in the Workbench, then opening a JPEG file from the Workbench would cause the file to be opened externally, in the system default editor.

Comment: Why downvote, please let me know I will delete my answer ?

Comment: dont know who has downvoted my question and your answer in the comments though my question was relevant it was just wasnt related to spring spring-mvc as correctly pointed by you its the default editor issue in eclipse.

Comment: its working thanks! please do upvote my question coz i have asked relevant query